# TableView not displaying whole tableViewCell (height)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I am on Xcode 8 with Swift 3 building a ViewController with a tableview and a custom cell.  I have multiple labels within a custom cell and I have set auto layout in my initialization with following code:

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 90.0
```

This is how it's set up on Xcode:

[image: My view controller with tableview and custom cell]

This is how it looks on simulator:

[image: on simulator]

I have tried setting constraints on the last label on the right with the same result at runtime.  Do I need to put the views in a container view like CollectionView or something?

Comment: You need a _complete_ set of constraints running from the top of the content view down through every label all the way to bottom of the content view. I see no evidence that you have done that.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8615862/custom-cell-row-height-setting-in-storyboard-is-not-responding

Comment: You need to make sure you have constraint on the bottom, like your bottom labels should have bottom constraint to the bottom of the cell otherwise the automatic calculation wont work

Comment: I am able to get cell row to show all the labels with setting up constraints and playing around with it like others have suggested.  Thanks

Comment: @Sonam Check 2 things for label . 1) is Lines set to 0 or not 2) have you given height constraint to labels then you need to make sure it has property >= set on it.link-: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45680791/getting-the-height-of-a-label-in-custom-cell-to-use-for-heightforrowat-in-my-mai?noredirect=1#comment78319803_45680791

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what constraint you have imposed. However, You must need to pin the first label to the top of the superview and last label to the bottom of the superview, to make the automatic dimension work. Also, make sure all the label have set their top and bottom to each other.

Answer (score 1):

Set the auto-constraint for the top, bottom, leading and trailing to whatever value you'd like. This value is however many pixels you would like to be off of the different margins. After that, add the following code to `viewDidLoad()`:

`tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
 tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100`

By using UITableViewAutomaticDimension you are telling the table view to use the Auto Layout constraints which will use the contents to determine the height.

To use UITableViewAutomaticDimension you need to specify a `estimatedRowHeight`. This value is an arbitrary value that will be the fallback, and you can use whatever value you think would be good for your project. Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Set your controller to be the tableview delegate.

Implement `tableView(_:heightForRowAt:)` method from the **UITableView protocol** and

```
return 90.0
```